# How to add an import to the file with Babel

Tags: babeljs

Say you have a file with:

```
AddReactImport();
```

And the plugin:

```
export default function ({types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      CallExpression(p) {
        if (p.node.callee.name === "AddReactImport") {
          // add import if it's not there
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

How do you add `import React from 'react';` at the top of the file/tree if it's not there already.

I think more important than the answer is how you find out how to do it. Please tell me because I'm having a hard time finding info sources on how to develop Babel plugins. My sources right now are: [Plugin Handbook](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md),[Babel Types](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-types), [AST Spec](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/ast/spec.md), [this blog post](http://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2015/09/13/lets-create-a-babel-plugin/), and the [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/). It feels like using an English-German dictionary to try to speak German.

Comment: For your use case you can just use [`babel-plugin-react-require`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-require). Good job if you're the one who made this plugin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
export default function ({types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Program(path) {
        const identifier = t.identifier('React');
        const importDefaultSpecifier = t.importDefaultSpecifier(identifier);
        const importDeclaration = t.importDeclaration([importDefaultSpecifier], t.stringLiteral('react'));
        path.unshiftContainer('body', importDeclaration);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Any way to check if the import has already been added? Either by the plugin itself, or pre-existing in src.

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71874291/399559

Answer (score 9):

If you want to inject code, just use `@babel/template` to generate the AST node for it; then inject it as you need to.

### Preamble: Babel documentation is not the best

I also agree that, even in 2020, information is sparse. I am getting most of my info by actually working through the `babel` source code, looking at all the tools (`types`, `traverse`, `path`, `code-frame` etc...), the helpers they use, existing plugins (e.g. `istanbul` to learn a bit about basic instrumentation in JS), the webpack `babel-loader` and more...

For example: `unshiftContainer` (and actually, `babel-traverse` in general) has no official documentation, but you can find it's source code [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-traverse/src/path/modification.js#L208) (fascinatingly enough, it accepts either a single node or an array of nodes!)

### Strategy #1 (updated version)

In this particular case, I would:

1. Create a [`@babel/template`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-template)
2. prepare that AST once at the start of my plugin
3. inject it into `Program` (i.e. the root path) once, only if the particular function call has been found

NOTE: Templates also support variables. Very useful if you want to wrap existing nodes or want to produce slight variations of the same code, depending on context.

#### Code (using Strategy #1)

```js
import template from "@babel/template";

// template
const buildImport = template(`
  import React from 'react';
`);

// plugin
const plugin = function () {
  const importDeclaration = buildImport();

  let imported = false;
  let root;
  return {
    visitor: {
      Program(path) {
        root = path;
      },
      CallExpression(path) {
        if (!imported && path.node.callee.name === "AddMyImport") {
          // add import if it's not there
          imported = true;
          root.unshiftContainer('body', importDeclaration);
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

### Strategy #2 (old version)

An alternative is:

1. use a utility function to generate an AST from source (`parseSource`)
2. prepare that AST once at the start of my plugin
3. inject it into `Program` (i.e. the root path) once, only if the particular function call has been found

#### Code (using Strategy #2)

Same as above but with your own compiler function (not as efficient as `@babel/template`):

```js
/**
 * Helper: Generate AST from source through `@babel/parser`.
 * Copied from somewhere... I think it was `@babel/traverse`
 * @param {*} source 
 */

export function parseSource(source) {
  let ast;
  try {
    source = `${source}`;
    ast = parse(source);
  } catch (err) {
    const loc = err.loc;
    if (loc) {
      err.message +=
        "\n" +
        codeFrameColumns(source, {
          start: {
            line: loc.line,
            column: loc.column + 1,
          },
        });
    }
    throw err;
  }

  const nodes = ast.program.body;
  nodes.forEach(n => traverse.removeProperties(n));
  return nodes;
}
```

### Possible Pitfalls

1. When a new node is injected/replaced etc, babel will run all plugins on them again. This is why your first instrumentation plugin is likely to encounter an infinite loop right of the bet: you want to remember and not re-visit previously visited nodes (I'm using a `Set` for that).
2. It gets worse when wrapping nodes. Nodes wrapped (e.g. with `@babel/template`) are actually copies, not the original node. In that case, you want to remember that it is instrumented and skip it in case you come across it again, or, again: infinite loop !
3. If you don't want to instrument nodes that have been emitted by any plugin (not just yours), that is you want to only operate on the original source code, you can skip them by checking whether they have a `loc` property (injected nodes usually do not have a `loc` property).
4. In your case, you are trying to add an `import` statement which won't always work without the right plugins enabled or without program-type set to `module`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's an even better way now: [babel-helper-module-imports](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-helper-module-imports)

For you the code would be

```js
import { addDefault } from "@babel/helper-module-imports";

addDefault(path, 'React', { nameHint: "React" })
```